# Why BroadcastReceiver crash when receive

Tags: android

I crash after I run the app.

Why does the BroadcastReceiver seem to cause an intent message to crash?

I would appreciate it if you could tell me where the problem is.

```
    test1.java

    public class test1 extends Activity
    {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           Intent intent = new Intent();
           sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }


AndroidManifest.xml

 <receiver android:name="Receiver"/>
```

Comment: can I see the log

Answer (score 0):

I don't think inner class will work as brodcastReciever. Try making a separate class. If that doesn't work Pls show what you actually wrote in intent.

Comment: Thank you. After adding the file, send the intent according to the package name.

Add Receiver.java and 

sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.test1.gogogo"));

com.test1 is from package com.test1;

android:name=".Receiver" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.test1.gogogo" />
            </intent-filter>